# How to make an active link with history push in an react component?

Tags: reactjs

The code bellow is a menu, I want to make an active link when i click, set to bold for example how can i do that?

```
    const TopMenuItem: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
        const { route } = props
        const { text, iconName } = menuItens[route.substring(1)] // Remove the '/' character

        function handleClick() {
            history.push(route)
        }

        return (
            <div className={ `MenuItem-${text}` } style={ containerStyle } onClick={ handleClick }>
                <Typography style={ {...fontStyle, fontWeight: 'bold'} }>{ text }</Typography>
                <Icon style={ arrowStyle }>keyboard_arrow_right_outline</Icon>
            </div>
        )
    }
    export default TopMenuItem

    const containerStyle = {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        cursor: 'pointer',
    }
    const fontStyle = {
        fontSize: '1em',
        letterSpacing: '1px',
        color: 'black',
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `react-router` package to create a menu. After installing react-router, you can import `NavLink` from it, which gives you access to `activeClassName` prop

`<NavLink exact={true} activeClassName='is-active' to='/some-path'>Home</NavLink>`

define css rule for your `is-active` class, and you'll be able to style your active menu item